# Getting this error: Property 'data' does not exist in type 'string'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```js
const loadOptions = async (inputValue: string, callback: (places: Place[]) => void) => {
        
        const response = await fetchLocalMapBox(inputValue)

        const places = response.data.features.map((item: any) => {
            return ({
                label: item.place_name,
                value: item.place_name,
                position: {
                    lat: item.center[1],
                    lng: item.center[0]
                },
                place: item.place_name,
            });
        });

        callback(places);
    };
```

It supposed to select an address and then search the address, but it gets an error:

> Property 'data' does not exist in type 'string'.ts(2339)

Someone could help with the issue??

Comment: Evidently `fetchLocalMapBox` returns `Promise<string>`, which resolves to a `string` which indeed doesn't have a `data` property. Without a [mre], that's all we can say.

Comment: You might need to do Json.parse() on the response

Comment: What does `fetchLocalMapBox` return? Looks like it returns something different than what you expect. On a side note, there is no need for a callback parameter on a function that already returns a `Promise` (since your function is `async` it returns one implicitly), you could just return `places` and use it directly afterwards where you call this function.